# How to prevent "No Line Found Error" while using the "While Loop?"

Tags: java

I have some code that reads input from a text file and converts it to mouse movement. The problem is that after a while when the file goes empty it returns a No Line Found Error. How do I prevent this? I tried checking whether it was null or not, but that didn't work. Here is the code:

```
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaRobotExample {

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        while (true) {
            Thread.sleep(3);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("W:/Mouse/X.txt"));
            BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("W:/Mouse/Y.txt"));

            if (br.readLine() == null || br2.readLine() == null) {
                System.out.println("No errors, and file empty");
                Robot robot3 = new Robot();
                robot3.mouseMove(0, 0);
                    continue;
            }

            Scanner file = new Scanner(new File("W:/Mouse/X.txt"));
            String x_contents = file.nextLine();
            file.close();
            System.out.println(x_contents);
            Scanner yfile = new Scanner(new File("W:/Mouse/Y.txt"));
            String y_contents = yfile.nextLine();
            file.close();
            System.out.println(y_contents);

            int x_int = Integer.parseInt(x_contents);
            int y_int = Integer.parseInt(y_contents);
            Robot robot = new Robot();
            robot.mouseMove(x_int, y_int);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Stack trace?  What's the full, complete text of the error message?

Comment: In addition to what @Israel Unterman answered, opening and closing the files and generating new Scanners in each iteration is probabably not what was intended. And `file` is closed twice while `yfile` is never closed. You might also look up the try-with-resources syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of checking `br` or `br2`, check the `file` of type `Scanner` with the method `hasNextLine()`. that is

```
if (file.hasNextLine()) ...
```